# How to prevent On Screen Keyboard from pushing content up?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, on-screen-keyboard

I'm building a React web app to be used on desktop and touch devices.

When the on screen keyboard appears after a user touches an input field, the entire content gets pushed up as the keyboard rises. This is normal functionality, but I'm looking for a way to prevent the keyboard from moving the content.

Has anyone done this before, or be able to point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: i guess your current input field gets moved when android opens its onscreen keyboard, correct ?

Comment: @Dirk Hey Dirk. I'm only testing on desktop ( chrome/safari/ie) and iOS devices so far. But you are correct with the input, along with everything else getting moved.